React - Contextmenu items with submenu, requires 2 clicks to close entire menu - MUI
I am new to react, please help.
React - Contextmenu items with submenu, requires 2 clicks to close entire menu - MUI
Instead it should close on a single click outside.
Also on mouse hover I need to show/hide submenus accordingly
I tried MouseEvents like mouseEnter/mouse Leave to set anchorEl,but it gives flickering.
Tried using timeout on mouseleave..but that doesn't allow me to select submenu
I tried using Menu and MenuItem provided by MUI.
